# Why is my Joomla! 2.5 Extension installing contents from the admin directory onto joomla but not from the site directory? (Code download available)

Tags: php, xml, joomla, installation, compression

Okay so the problem is.. my joomla module  is not installing correctly. Orginial contents of autobase.xml is based off the [joomla 2.5 docs for HelloWorld](https://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_(MVC)_Component_for_Joomla!2.5_-_Part_15). I have two directories in the com_autobase.zip called **admin** and **site**, For some unknown reason the files from **site** are not being transferred into **Joomla/Components/Com_autobase**. But instead the files from **admin** are being transferred both into *Components/com_autobase* and *Administrator/Components/com_autobase*

admin folder 'com_autobase.zip'

[image: admin folder installer]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/bf3m5asl.ofm.png))</sub>

site folder 'com_autobase.zip'

[image: site folder installer]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/dfn4xw5o.0cv.png))</sub>

autobase.xml contents from 'com_autobase' and 'com_autobase/admin'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- $Id: helloworld.xml 14 2009-11-02 18:35:20Z chdemko $ -->
<extension type="component" version="1.6.0" method="upgrade">

<name>AutoBase</name>
<!-- The following elements are optional and free of formatting conttraints -->
<creationDate>July 2012</creationDate>
<authorUrl>http://www.triotech.co.nz</authorUrl>
<copyright>Copyright Info</copyright>
<license>License Info</license>
<!--  The version string is recorded in the components table -->
<version>0.0.24</version>
<!-- The description is optional and defaults to the name -->
<description>This application has been built using PHP in house at Trio Technology Ltd as a third party
application for the AutoBase Car Yard</description>

<install> <!-- Runs on install -->
    <sql>
        <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/install.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
    </sql>
</install>
<uninstall> <!-- Runs on uninstall -->
    <sql>
        <file driver="mysql" charset="utf8">sql/uninstall.mysql.utf8.sql</file>
    </sql>
</uninstall>
<update> <!-- Runs on update; New in 1.6 -->
    <schemas>
        <schemapath type="mysql">sql/updates/mysql</schemapath>
    </schemas>
</update>

<!-- Site Main File Copy Section -->
<!-- Note the folder attribute: This attribute describes the folder
    to copy FROM in the package to install therefore files copied
    in this section are copied from /site/ in the package -->
<files folder="site">
    <filename>index.html</filename>
    <filename>autobase.php</filename>
    <filename>controller.php</filename>
    <filename>definitions.php</filename>
    <filename>imageController.php</filename>
    <folder>views</folder>
    <folder>js</folder>
    <folder>css</folder>
    <folder>helpers</folder>
    <folder>models</folder>
    <folder>cache</folder>
    <folder>images</folder>
</files>

<administration>
    <!-- Administration Menu Section -->
    <menu>AutoBase!</menu>
    <!-- Administration Main File Copy Section -->
    <!-- Note the folder attribute: This attribute describes the folder
        to copy FROM in the package to install therefore files copied
        in this section are copied from /admin/ in the package -->
    <files folder="admin">
        <!-- Admin Main File Copy Section -->
        <filename>index.html</filename>
        <filename>autobase.php</filename>
        <filename>controller.php</filename>
        <!-- SQL files section -->
        <folder>sql</folder>
        <!-- tables files section -->
        <folder>tables</folder>
        <!-- models files section -->
        <folder>models</folder>
        <!-- views files section -->
        <folder>views</folder>
        <!-- views helpers section -->
        <folder>helpers</folder>
    </files>
</administration>

</extension>
```

'com_autobase.zip' INSTALLER package preview

[image: package]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/zcga3oyx.cs2.png))</sub>

But when I install my packaged zip file, I get this error.. "**File does not exist: admin/definitions.php**" (which should be expected because this file is in the **site diectory** and not the **admin directory**).

[image: joomla error]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/htlotipf.mgk.png))</sub>

Which is telling me its trying to find the files/folders that are located in the **site** directory, but with the **admin directory**. How can I get my extensions files from site and admin to be transferred to the correct location? on the joomla CMS.

site folder 'com_autobase.zip' (preview from windows, as you see the **definitions.php** is there).

[image: site windows installer]
<sub>(source: [iforce.co.nz](http://iforce.co.nz/i/j5coups5.aqo.png))</sub>

DOWNLOAD of the installer is available [here](https://rapidshare.com/files/1006577725/com_autobase.zip)

Comment: seems very odd. Have you tried installing the component on a fresh copy of Joomla? Also, try a different compression method such as using the standard windows one. If not feel free to send it my way and I will be more than happy to test and try and find a solution. Regards

Comment: @Lodder I've just installed fresh [Joomla! 2.5.6 English (UK) Full Package](http://www.joomla.org/download.html) (I've also dropped all the previous tables) and I've compressed the extension with Standard Windows 7 (Send to Zip) and I'm still getting the `JInstaller :Install: File does not exist C:\path\to\file\admin\definitions.php` error. Sent, thank you.

Comment: did you send it? cause I haven't received an e-mail. E-mail address on my profile. regards

Comment: @Loddder I sent it to lodder (at) hotmail (dot) com which I managed to find [here](http://lynx.tmfserver.com/index.php?site=profile&id=121). But I can't seem to find your email address on your profile, all I can see is a website address (and the registration seems to be broken on the captcha :(). In the mean time I've published the question on joomla forums too [here](http://forum.joomla.org/posting.php?mode=reply&f=642&t=727263) (An attachment is available there). Regards

Comment: @Lodder alternatively I've provided a link from rapidshare to the `com_autobase.zip` file. On the question.

Comment: @Killrwar, ok thanks, will download from rapidshare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok found the solution to your problem. In the `admin` folder, delete the `autobase.xml` file and also add an `index.html` file to the `cache` folder. I think Joomla doesn't like installing folders that are empty. Once you have done this, it should install fine.

Regards.

Comment: that damn install.xml inside the admin folder was the problem